# Minimal Discriminants

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $D_n$ be the minimal absolute value of the discriminants of
number fields with degree $n$. Arnold Scholz conjectured in 1936 that 
$D_{397} > D_{400}$, which is, of course, still open (Scholz had
constructed a field with degree $400$ and "small" discriminant by
taking the Hilbert class field of the field of $55$-th roots of 
unity). But are there any chances of finding an integer $n$ such 
that $D_n > D_{n+1}$? Are there reasons to believe that Odlyzko's 
lower bounds can be improved for prime values of the degree?

What about the corresponding question for the root discriminants
$E_n = D_n^{1/n}$? I would be grateful for any suitable reference or
heuristic argument.

Comment: Odlyzko mentions this problem in his survey paper http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/arch/discriminant.survey.pdf asking whether the root discriminant goes to infinity for prime degrees (see open problem 2.4).  I don't think much more is known about it, although I would love to be wrong here!